# Put user controls in a grid with using specific order

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, wpf-controls

I'm starting with WPF and I have a grid [3-3] (Matrix). I want to define an order of putting my user-controls in that grid.

So, can I make it using Xaml data-binding ? or I have to creat an "AddControls" Method and specifiy the order manualy ?

Here is an example of the order i want to establish in my grid :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` with a `UniformGrid` as `ItemsPanel`.

If the default order is not correct you could either try subclassing the panel or binding to a collection and inserting at the right place. Of course you can also set the items directly in XAML, there the element order specifies the order in which the items are added.

Comment: can you explain me more please, what do you mean by: "binding to a collection and inserting at **the right place** " because that's what I'm trying to do ! So if I understant I'll re-order my elements in my collection, right ??

Comment: @Alvaro: Yes, i just meant that the panel has a default layout and if you want an item at a specific place you need to take that into consideration when adding the items. (Also if you modify the collection after it has been set if would recommend an `ObservableCollection` as it notifies the control)